# Is it any way to upload new apk to Google Play automatically?

Tags: android, google-play

It is possible  to  upload  new  apk  to Google  Play  automatically? I mean not for already published apps (that have at least one APK uploaded), but for  creating  absolutely new  application  and upload its first apk. There  is  tools  like  Publisher  API, Fastlane etc, but  they  are  uploading  apk's  for  update  already published  apps.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with current android-publisher API version (all the other tools, including fastlane, are built on top of that).

From [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/edits/):

> You can only use this API to make changes to an **existing** app (that has
>   at least one APK uploaded); thus, you will have to upload at least one
>   APK through the Play Console before you can use this API.